# Example of wrapped document/literal array

Tags: php, arrays, xml, soap

I've having trouble finding a solid example of a simple array in a wrapped document/literal style.

Consider a PHP function that generates an array up to a max count.

```
/**
 * @param int $max
 * @return string[] $count
 */
public function countTo($max)
{
    $array = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
        $array[] = 'Number: ' . ($i + 1);
    }
    return $array;
}
```

The WSDL types generated for this are:

```
<xsd:complexType name="countTo">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="max" type="xsd:int"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="countTo" nillable="true" type="ns:countTo"/>
<xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfCount">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="count" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="countToResponse">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="count" type="ns:ArrayOfCount"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="countToResponse" nillable="true" type="ns:countToResponse"/>
```

The request in the body would look like:

```
<ns1:countTo>
  <max>5</max>
</ns1:countTo>
```

But what does the response look like, and what is the convention?

Currently, SoapServer is generating

```
<ns1:countToResponse>
  <count>
    <count>Number: 1</count>
    <count>Number: 2</count>
    <count>Number: 3</count>
    <count>Number: 4</count>
    <count>Number: 5</count>
  </count>
</ns1:countToResponse>
```

I'm not sure about the nested `count` elements.  Perhaps this should be `item` instead (and the WSDL would need to be updated to make it happen).

```
<ns1:countToResponse>
  <count>
    <item>Number: 1</item>
    <item>Number: 2</item>
    <item>Number: 3</item>
    <item>Number: 4</item>
    <item>Number: 5</item>
  </count>
</ns1:countToResponse>
```

Comment: do you need sample of new wsdl-schema (for response as `<count><item></item>..</count>`) or what ?

Comment: What I'm after is the accepted convention for the actual XML produced for wrapped document/literal.  There is plenty of documentation around for what the WSDL might look like, and how it should differ from the RPC version.  Just nothing around on what the accepted practices are for the produced wrapped document/literal XML.

Comment: This seems like an opinion question to me. You could easily do either one and I have had the misfortune of dealing with systems that use both.

Comment: @yakatz "There is no convention for arrays in wrapped document/literal" is also an answer. It becomes opinion when a preference has no authority to back it up as convention or otherwise. What was the misfortune with systems that use both, or either?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really is no convention for this. It sometimes is convenient when you have an array of `item` to name the collection `items`. But since your element is named `count` is a bit more difficult, since `counts` would not be an accepted answer. You might choose `result`, but that would only fit when it is also the only container element, as in your example.

```
<xsd:complexType name="countToResponse">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="result" type="ns:ArrayOfCount"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```